# Rapid, successfull new windows in ASP.NET/C# Loop via JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, popup

I'm attempting to open 1-6 potential valid popups (in reality it's a foreach item in a valid collection) via a registered startup script like this:

```
While (int i < 6)
{
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(System.Web.UI.Page), "OpenWin", "<script type='text/javascript'>openNewWin    ('" + url + "')</script>", false);
i++;
}
```

The markup is as follows:

```
  <head>
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function openNewWin(url) 
        {
            var x = window.open(url, 'mynewwin', 'width=620,height=250,toolbar=1');
            x.focus();
        }
   </script>
 </head>
```

But I'm only seeing one window open, when i step through, the code seems to execute successfully, what gives?

Comment: "1-6 potential valid popups" - 6 popups? That's going to be a great User Experience!

Comment: @Mitch Wheat I knew I'd get this lol.  Let's just say, there will be 6 once.... and typically only 1-2 if ever more than 1 at a time after that... I'll send you a message explaining the concept if you'll promise to upvote the post if it makes sense. :)

Comment: @Mitch Wheat No faith in humanity anymore...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `window.open` call, you are using the same name (`mynewwin`).  Thus each subsequent call to `open` results in the URL being loaded into the first window with that name.  You could use `_blank` and it would open each in a new window:

```
var x = window.open(url, '_blank', 'width=620,height=250,toolbar=1');
```

That being said, I agree that it's difficult to imagine this not being a poor user experience.

Comment: Ah, something so simple. :) I appreciate the quick answer. Rest assured I'm not a spam, popup creator. But rather I understand the idea that a tiny, attractively designed visual indicator as a milestone of accomplishment draws attention and desire to continue progressing toward a specific goal.  Hrm.....

Comment: @Kulingar, not sure how 6-popups will facilitate that goal, but I trust that you do. :)

Comment: +1. @Kulingar, with multiple popups you most likly achive "this is likely porn/ads only site, I'd better close it till it is not too late". Please consider using positioned HTML elements on the same page instead of opening separate windows.